# Oscommerce to Magento

Tags: migration

I am currently considering changing my oscommerce store to Magento.
It's a hard decision though, and not sure if its worth it. I just feel that oscommerce might be limiting my growth.

What are your thoughts? (obviously you'll be recommending Magento) 
Has any of you had experience with oscommerce and can compare the two?

What should I consider, when making my choice?

I currently have pretty good order volume, but oscommerce lacks some basic functionality and reports, that would require my oscommerce to be rebuilt.

Comment: Although this is a Q&A for Magento i'm not sure that automatically means Magento is the right tool for the job. You need to consider what problems OScommerce causes and whether Magento is a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with osCommerce ages ago and can tell you from experience you can do a lot more with Magento. I took a quick look at the 'latest' version of osCommerce [on github](https://github.com/osCommerce/oscommerce) and noticed the code hasn't changed for 3 years which means the platform is pretty outdated.

Next to that, since osCommerce seems to be a dying platform finding good developers or agencies that can help you update your shop will get harder and harder while finding Magento developers and agencies should be a lot easier.

So in short: Choose Magento and migrate your shop as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is an amazing tool, but there's a BIG learning curve.
So the first thing to make sure is that you have the time (and commitment) to learn all the necessary coding knowledge. (The amount of coding you need to learn is based on how much customisation of the basic site you want to do)

Comment: Phil, I don't expect to do any coding, but have somebody do that for me. I'm terrible at coding, but good at running my shop.
My main problem with oscommerce, has been that the more custom features i have made for it, the more complicated it gets to add even more features.
I currently want a reporting feature, to calculate margin reports, but the programmers i work with, tell me that this is too complicated, and would mean that the whole shop needs to be built up from scratch.
This is why i am considering buildin it up in Magento instead

Comment: @StefanosJensen, please note that software entropy is not foreign to Magento. There is a lot of people who program for Magento, but I've only seen a few who do it right. When you don't code Magento right, it becomes pretty nasty and things can get progressively harder to achieve, as in the case you have with OScommerce. I would go with Magento, if I were you, but check with your "somebody" that he or she knows the Magento way.

Answer (score 0):

- Magento community has grown much larger as compared to oscommerce.
- oscommerce has not been updated for last 3 years (around).
- Magento is much better than oscommerce in terms of features.
- Magento offers multi-stores management from a single installation.
- There are many extensions available for extending functionality.

**Some more features of Magento which Oscommerce does not have:**

- Import/ Export
- Coupons
- Email templates
- One page checkout
- Wish List
- Last but not the least, you can find lot of developers if you have any development requirement.